# Publish bot in Microsoft Botframework with Twilio for WhatsApp

Tags: twilio, botframework, azure-qna-maker

After developing a Chatbot with Microsoft Bot Framework and publishing it in the Azure portal I want to use it in WhatsApp. For that I am using a WhatsApp Sandbox in Twilio, but now I don't know how I can make the adapter in Azure to use my bot in WhatsApp.

Can someone guide me what steps should I follow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Bot Integration with Whatsapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52114485/microsoft-bot-integration-with-whatsapp)

Comment: @EddynsonVega - Are you still working on this? (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @KyleDelaney Thank you very much for responding, I am still working on this and I am not yet sure how to proceed since my bot develops it from bot framework composer and not from code.

Comment: @EddynsonVega - Did you have a look at the answers that Yves linked you to?

Comment: @KyleDelaney The case is that the bot is developed with Bot Framework Composer, so there is no code, as I can add the WhatsApp adapter to use the bot?

Comment: @EddynsonVega - If you export the runtime, you can do anything with a Composer bot that you can with a normal bot. Have you tried exporting the runtime? https://learn.microsoft.com/composer/how-to-add-custom-action#export-the-bot-runtime

Comment: @EddynsonVega - Are you still working on this?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I'm sorry, I couldn't connect it. I'm not sure the process to follow.

Comment: @EddynsonVega - All right, did you try following the process in the document I linked to?

Comment: @EddynsonVega - Are you still working on this?